# Coap URI-PATCH for openthread simulator

Tags: openthread

I´m working in a scientic work and I need to use the openthread simulator.
By the documentation (above) to set the coap resource is necessary to use the uri-path, does anyone have an examle how to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Ricardo
https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/master/src/cli/README_COAP.md#resource-uri-path

resource [uri-path]

Sets the URI path for the test resource.

> coap resource test-resource Done > coap resource test-resource Done
> Sets the URI path for the test resource.

> coap resource test-resource
> Done
> coap resource test-resource Done

Answer (score 0):

The URI-Path to the path component of the URI. If you need the CoAP server to read data from a file when responding to a CoAP Request, you will need to write the code to do so. You can reference [src/cli/cli_coap.cpp](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/master/src/cli/cli_coap.cpp) for example code. In particular, you can see where the resource content is retrieved in [src/cli/cli_coap.cpp#L630](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/97d416be9edd5a6aa4427568fbc0922c79cc0446/src/cli/cli_coap.cpp#L630).

Comment: Thanks a lot jhui, I will follow these steps. 

Regards

Ricardo